# Changing the color of itemize item in beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, color, itemize

I would like to change the color of `itemize item` and `itemize subitem` (the bullet) throughout the presentation. I was wondering how I can do that. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass [11 pt, xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer} 
\usepackage{pgf, pgfpages}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{beamerhighlight}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\blacksquare$}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\blacktriangleright$}
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item hey
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end {document}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

How about

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{yellow}$\blacksquare$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{orange}$\blacktriangleright$}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass {beamer} 

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{yellow}$\blacksquare$}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{orange}$\blacktriangleright$}
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item hey
\begin{itemize}
    \item hey
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end {document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. the only thing is that if you want to change the color of Math, the suggested solution will not work any more. As an example, adding the following coe to the MWE will turn the color of itemize to black.    `\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{parent=math text}
\setbeamercolor{math text displayed}{parent=math text}
\setbeamercolor{normal text in math text}{}`. Any suggestion?

Comment: @NNik move the `\color...` stuff inside the `$...$` :)

Answer (score 26):

[image]

The colors for the itemize symbols can be set as any other color in beamer by using `\setbeamercolor`, the symbolbols themselves by `\setbeamertemplate`.

The following code was used to get the result above.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=cyan}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{itemize colors and symbols}
\begin{itemize}
    \item a red square
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a blue circle
        \begin{itemize}
            \item a cyan triangle
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me, at least in beamerposter:
`\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=yellow,bg=white}`.